# FileStream path's format is not supported Exception

Tags: c#, io

This is the code to create the stream reader. It uses a stream reader to read all the lines from the file.

```
        try {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader( new FileStream(@"" + defaultPath + file, FileMode.Open))) {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                    fileContents.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }
```

It gives an error when I call it

```
System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
```

This is the exact error:

```
 System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported. at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access) at HackEr.LuaFileReader.ReadFile(String file) in C:\Users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HackEr\HackEr\HackEr\LuaFileReader.cs:line 30
```

Do I need to add the arguments to the new filestream?
I'm using C# so the filestream can be created using the arguments (string, FileMode).

Comment: Can you post the error being written to the stack?

Comment: What use is `@"" + `? Also change `e.StackTrace` to `e.ToString()` for a better error report.

Comment: `System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at HackEr.LuaFileReader.ReadFile(String file) in C:\Users\brandon\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HackEr\HackEr\HackEr\LuaFileReader.cs:line 30`

Comment: Right, seems like the path passed is not good. What is the path?

Comment: C:\Users\brandon\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\HackEr\HackEr\HackEr\bin\x86\Debug\files\test.txt

Comment: @Brandon Woolworth post the values of `defaultPath` and the `file` variables please.

Comment: One guess is that there is no trailing '\' in defaultPath. Use `new FileStream(Path.Combine(defaultPath, file), FileMode.Open)` instead. That works whether or not the trailing '\' is there.

Comment: In XNA you use whatever works in plain C#, because essentially XNA is built upon C#, and strictly speaking XNA is not a programming language, but a framework. So it's perfectly fine to use the approach you thought wouldn't work.

Comment: The exception message is very selective, it says that your string contains a colon at a position other than the second char in the string.  Like "cd:\foo\bar.txt".